# Word for: powering up an electronic prototype for the first time

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a technical term for performing the following activity.

In electronics, when a person designs a device (or a circuit board) and has it manufactured, the next phase is to:

- Perform preliminary checks before connecting it to power for the first time.
- Sometimes power only parts of it, incrementally, making sure it doesn't burn out, etc.
- While at it, checking that various parameters are within specifications.
- Find and fix any minor issues or parts that are not working as intended.

In my native language (Czech), there is a word for this (oživení), roughly translated as **revival**.

Is there a matching term in English?

Comment: In the case of software this could be *incremental testing*. Others may say if it applies to hardware too.

Comment: If the prototype is completely defective, next iteration of it would be made, yes. What I'm looking for is the act of "trying out" or "activating" the current one. Or rather, to bring it up into somewhat/partially/fully operational state.

Comment: When I was helping design the IBM 5100 in the mid 70s we called the first power-on the "smoke test" -- turn it on and see what smokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the procedure that consist in putting the creation to **bench testing** or to a **bench test**.

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bench-test)) ***bench test***      the critical evaluation of a new or repaired component, device, apparatus, etc, prior to installation to ensure that it is in perfect condition